# version 18 react

Tags: reactjs, useeffect

en la versión 18 de react no permite colocar un array vacío como segundo argumento en el useEfecct me salta el siguiente error " React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'history'. Either include it or remove the dependency array"

este es mi código

```
function Listado(){
const history = useHistory();

 useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      if (token === null) {
        history.push('/');
         }
      }, []);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te dice es que incluyas o elimine la matriz de dependencia,
intenta hacerlo de esta manera eso permite, estar al tanto de los cambios del localStorage

```
 const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
 const history = useHistory();
 
  useEffect(() => {
      if (token === null) {
        history.push('/');
      }
  }, [token]);
```

si no funciona agrégale al array [token, history]

Answer (score 0):

El error es bastante explanatorio por sí mismo.

`useEffect` es un hook de React que ejecuta 'efectos' o en otras palabras, ejecuta el código de la función que le pasamos cuando una de sus dependencias cambian.

En tu caso, entiendo que solo quieres que funcione una vez: ESLINT te está diciendo que estás haciendo uso de history, y history puede que no esté listo al principio; lo correcto sería que metas history dentro del array de dependencias.

No te preocupes por ejecutarse más de una vez ya que history no cambiará durante toda la ejecución.

```
function Listado(){
const history = useHistory();

 useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      if (token === null) {
        history.push('/');
         }
      }, [history]);
```

Answer (score -1):

La advertencia "React Hook useEffect tiene una dependencia faltante" ocurre cuando el useEffect hook hace uso de una variable o función que no hemos incluido en su matriz de dependencia. Para resolver el error, deshabilite la regla para una línea o mueva la variable dentro del enlace useEffect.

```
function Listado(){


useEffect(() => {
 const history = useHistory();
 const token = 
 localStorage.getItem("token");
  if (token === null) {
    history.push('/');
     }
  }, []);
```

Esto elimina la advertencia porque el enlace ya no depende del objeto porque se declara dentro de él.